# Java ASM CheckClassAdapter on ClassNode

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

The ASM CheckClassAdapter is very useful for obtaining useful log output about why a class failed in the case of verify errors, however it cannot be used where the stackmap frames are invalid.
The CheckClassAdapter can't be used for these situations because of it accepting a ClassReader, meaning that to use it to check my transformed ClassNode I have to do the following:

```
ClassWriter verifyWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
classNode.accept(verifyWriter);
CheckClassAdapter.verify(new ClassReader(verifyWriter.toByteArray()), true, printDumpLogFile);
```

When the ClassWriter fails because of the bytecode of my ClassNode being strangely invalid, the output passed into the CheckClassAdapter is invalid and very malformed with many empty frames and NOPs. Is there any way to pass a ClassNode into the CheckClassAdapter, avoiding having to use a ClassWriter which limits its usefulness?

Comment: Can you please share one or several of your problematic class files? I would like to try something.

Comment: BTW, how do you create `classNode`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way of obtaining the input class' byte code instead of a `ClassNode`, you can use something like this:

```java
CheckClassAdapter.verify(
  bytes,
  true,
  new PrintWriter(System.out)
);
```

For example, if the byte code is already stored in a class file, you can do this:

```java
CheckClassAdapter.verify(
  new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(args[0])),
  true,
  new PrintWriter(System.out)
);
```

But actually, if the stackmap frames are invalid, the `CheckClassAdapter` might not report anything. At least I have class files in which it does not. The same applies to `org.apache.bcel.verifier.Verifier`, by the way. Still, the JVM throws a `VerifyError`, i.e. loading the class into an actual JVM is the ultimate check.

Comment: I should have been more explicit, the class file being read is transformed at runtime, the verifier being added for when that transformed class fails to be written. The verifier is there to help debug problems with the code. I already have it dumping the problematic generated class' code using the TraceClassVisitor, but using the verifier makes it a lot more clear where the problem is than relying on JVM errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, creating a class that extends CheckClassAdapter and adding a method with the ClassNode parameter. Reading the CheckClassAdapter's source, I found that that ClassReader visits a class node anyway.

```
public static void verify(
  final ClassReader classReader,
  final ClassLoader loader,
  final boolean printResults,
  final PrintWriter printWriter) {
ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
classReader.accept(
    new CheckClassAdapter(/*latest*/ Opcodes.ASM10_EXPERIMENTAL, classNode, false) {},
    ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);
```

As you can see, ASM could expose a method to just input in the ClassNode, but for some reason has not.

Here is code to a class that extends CheckClassAdapter, adding this functionality:

```
public class CheckClassAdapterClassNode extends CheckClassAdapter {

public CheckClassAdapterClassNode(ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
    super(classVisitor);
}

/**
 * Checks the given class.
 *
 * @param classNode the class to be checked.
 * @param loader a <code>ClassLoader</code> which will be used to load referenced classes. May be
 *     {@literal null}.
 * @param printResults whether to print the results of the bytecode verification.
 * @param printWriter where the results (or the stack trace in case of error) must be printed.
 */
public static void verify(
        final ClassNode classNode,
        final ClassLoader loader,
        final boolean printResults,
        final PrintWriter printWriter) {

    Type syperType = classNode.superName == null ? null : Type.getObjectType(classNode.superName);
    List<MethodNode> methods = classNode.methods;

    List<Type> interfaces = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String interfaceName : classNode.interfaces) {
        interfaces.add(Type.getObjectType(interfaceName));
    }

    for (MethodNode method : methods) {
        SimpleVerifier verifier =
                new SimpleVerifier(
                        Type.getObjectType(classNode.name),
                        syperType,
                        interfaces,
                        (classNode.access & Opcodes.ACC_INTERFACE) != 0);
        Analyzer<BasicValue> analyzer = new Analyzer<>(verifier);
        if (loader != null) {
            verifier.setClassLoader(loader);
        }
        try {
            analyzer.analyze(classNode.name, method);
        } catch (AnalyzerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        }
        if (printResults) {
            printAnalyzerResult(method, analyzer, printWriter);
        }
    }
    printWriter.flush();
}

static void printAnalyzerResult(
        final MethodNode method, final Analyzer<BasicValue> analyzer, final PrintWriter printWriter) {
    Textifier textifier = new Textifier();
    TraceMethodVisitor traceMethodVisitor = new TraceMethodVisitor(textifier);

    printWriter.println(method.name + method.desc);
    for (int i = 0; i < method.instructions.size(); ++i) {
        if (method.instructions.get(i) == null) continue;
        method.instructions.get(i).accept(traceMethodVisitor);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Frame<BasicValue> frame = analyzer.getFrames()[i];
        if (frame == null) {
            stringBuilder.append('?');
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < frame.getLocals(); ++j) {
                stringBuilder.append(getUnqualifiedName(frame.getLocal(j).toString())).append(' ');
            }
            stringBuilder.append(" : ");
            for (int j = 0; j < frame.getStackSize(); ++j) {
                stringBuilder.append(getUnqualifiedName(frame.getStack(j).toString())).append(' ');
            }
        }
        while (stringBuilder.length() < method.maxStack + method.maxLocals + 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        printWriter.print(Integer.toString(i + 100000).substring(1));
        printWriter.print(
                " " + stringBuilder + " : " + textifier.text.get(textifier.text.size() - 1));
    }
    for (TryCatchBlockNode tryCatchBlock : method.tryCatchBlocks) {
        tryCatchBlock.accept(traceMethodVisitor);
        printWriter.print(" " + textifier.text.get(textifier.text.size() - 1));
    }
    printWriter.println();
}

private static String getUnqualifiedName(final String name) {
    int lastSlashIndex = name.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (lastSlashIndex == -1) {
        return name;
    } else {
        int endIndex = name.length();
        if (name.charAt(endIndex - 1) == ';') {
            endIndex--;
        }
        return name.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
}

}
```

I will likely create an issue on the ASM repo and add a pull request to add this.

Comment: I have not analysed your code, but I am happy that you were able to solve your problem. When you have enough reputation points here, you can also accept your own answer in order to close the question. Please also edit your answer, adding a link to the ASM issue and/or PR for further reference. Thank you.

Comment: I would also be interested in seeing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the diagnostic output for your class file with the bogus stackmap. Is there anything you can recognise? In my own case I do not see anything suspicious, as if everything was fine, but in fact it is not. I do not use a `TraceMethodVisitor` in addition to the `CheckClassAdapter`, though. I am not an ASM pro, so I would like to learn something as a take-away from this issue.

Comment: There is no need to create a subclass to copy a `static` method. Besides that, for what you want to check, a simple `classNode.accept(new CheckClassAdapter(null));` would be enough.